# How to Convert a date YYYY-MM-DD to a string YYYYMM, using Big Query SQL Standard?

Tags: sql, date, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, converters

Got a Export_date field with YYYY-MM-DD. I'd like to get YYYYMM as output.

input : 2020-06-02
Expected output : 202006

I'm using SQL Standard in GCP Bigquery

How to Convert a date YYYY-MM-DD to a string YYYYMM, using Big Query SQL Standard ?

I've tried this function

```
substr(cast(export_date as string), 0,7) as date,
```

But I got YYYY-DD as output (2020-06)

Thank you

Comment: if your column is a STRING and not DATE (as you state in comments to Gordon's answer), why in this case you had `cast(export_date as string)` in your tries?! See  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `format_timestamp`:

```
SELECT format_timestamp('%Y%m', '2020-06-02')
```

it gives back `'202006'`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is:

```
select extract(year from export_date) * 100 + extract(month from export_date) as yyyymm
```

You could also format this as a string using `date_format()`.

If your value is stored as a string and not a date, then just use string functions:

```
select concat(substr(export_date, 1, 4), substr(export_date, 6, 2))
```

Comment: Got this errot message : No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART FROM STRING.
Thanks anyway !

Comment: @CallmeJezza . . . Your question implies that the column is a date and should be stored as a `date`.  If it is a string, then just use string operations.